# How does hiding work in combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, stealth

Last session, I was running, as DM, the adventure from the Starter Set(Lost Mine of Phandelver) and one of the pregenerated characters is a Lightfoot Halfing Rogue with the Naturally Stealthy ability, which a player was using to hide during combat.

> **Naturally Stealthy**. You can attempt to hide even when you are obscured only by a creature that is at least one size larger than you.(PHB p.28)

My problem is that I am confused as to what hiding means. Are you considered hidden only when you're stationary and/or behind some kind of cover or does it mean that even if you move, you're "lurking in the shadows" so you can still have the Unseen Attackers advantage?

Answer (score 0):

It means without an active perception check they don't know where you are, so yes you gain any ability that hiding would confer.

Comment: Correction, the perception check can also be passive, PHB 177: When you hide, there's a chance someone will notice you even if they aren't searching (followed by passive perception check description).